# Font awesome css cannot load relevant font files

Tags: css, font-awesome

Font awesome css placed in `prototype/css/views/`. Font files is in `prototype/css/views/fonts` folder. Also I have declared `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/views/font-awesome.min.css"/>`. I have `<i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-4x"></i>`.

I can access them by directly typing their url in Chrome. For some reason it is not loaded and `[]` is displayed. How to fix it?

UPDATE:

It starts to work when I replace `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/views/font-awesome.min.css"/>`
 with `<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
 But I need css and font to be placed on my site...

Comment: Are you getting any error from the console when loading the page?

Comment: Absolutely no error.

Comment: Open the "Network" tab under Chrome DevTools and reload the page and see if the all the requests to the font files are made and successful.

Comment: CSS file loads with no problems. But there is no record of any fonts loaded.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/views/fonts/font-awesome.min.css"/>` instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/views/font-awesome.min.css"/>` as you said that you have your font files in `prototype/css/views/fonts` ?

Comment: You should see a 404 error if the path is incorrect. It's probably a MIME type problem i.e. you are serving the fonts with the wrong `Content-Type`.

Comment: @user2915402 I know it would appear a 404 error but he said that fonts are on a different folder from what he linked with css. Maybe it's a Typo?

Comment: To the OP: try using full URL instead of relative paths in the @font-face declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need the relative path from your CSS file to the font file (not from HTML to font). Also think you need to update the css file to have the correct path to the font file.

Try `href="/prototype/css/views/font-awesome.min.css"`

And in font-awesome.min.css edit the paths to `fonts/FONT.EXT`

Comment: does it `../fonts/` refers to site `root/fonts` folder?